# Error in Training yolov3 Model [ Allocate additional workspace_size = 12.46 MB ]

Tags: python

I got this error message while i'm training Yolov3 model with max_batches = 8000 and 27 filter and 4 classess
this is the code:
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_training.cfg /mydrive/yolov3/yolov3_training_last.weights -dont_show

this is the ERROR:
Allocate additional workspace_size = 12.46 MB
Loading weights from /mydrive/yolov3/yolov3_training_last.weights...Couldn't open file: /mydrive/yolov3/yolov3_training_last.weights

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a couple things that you can try to fix this:

First thing, check if your allocating enough memory or if your GPU is running out of memory. What type of GPU and VRAM do you have?

If you are running out of memory, you will have to decrease the batch size and subdivisions in your .cfg file.

Second, if you are using CUDA, you need to navigate to the Darknet makefile and look for(it should be) line 7, a line looking something like this.

```
ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \
```

You have to replace your architecture here.
The darknet repo does not contain it, but the YoloV4 repo by AlexeyAB contains the ARCH params for different GPUS, just match with your GPU. If your GPU isn't here you are going to have to look that up.

```
# Tesla V100
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_70,code=[sm_70,compute_70]

# GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, RTX 2080, RTX 2070, Quadro RTX 8000, Quadro RTX 6000, Quadro RTX 5000, Tesla T4, XNOR Tensor Cores
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_75,code=[sm_75,compute_75]

# Jetson XAVIER
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_72,code=[sm_72,compute_72]

# GTX 1080, GTX 1070, GTX 1060, GTX 1050, GTX 1030, Titan Xp, Tesla P40, Tesla P4
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# GP100/Tesla P100 - DGX-1
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60

# For Jetson TX1, Tegra X1, DRIVE CX, DRIVE PX - uncomment:
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_53,code=[sm_53,compute_53]

# For Jetson Tx2 or Drive-PX2 uncomment:
# ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_62,code=[sm_62,compute_62]
```

Let me know if this works for you, these I think might be the pressing issues at hand.